# "Can't be bothered" equivalent without "can't"?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

How do I change my statement of "I can't be bothered" to not include the word *can't*?
My family are trying to take *can't* out of our vocabulary.

Comment: "My family are trying to take *can't* out of our vocabulary." They can't.

Comment: One assumes that they're addressing negative attitudes rather than unfavoured styles of communication per se. Any synonym of 'I can't be bothered' is surely a prime candidate for eschewing.

Comment: Literally or figuratively? It _does_ make a difference.

Comment: @joan-middlemiss you can try "it's too bothersome for me to care" :)

Comment: I won't be bothered.

Comment: It's not possible that I can be bothered.

Comment: "I'm lacking in interest". "The spirit is weak, too"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saying "I can't take out the garbage." you could say, "I decline to take out the garbage." or "Taking out the garbage will cause me to the bus."
I doubt that you will find a single word to replace "can't".
You CAN hope that your family soon discovers that this exercise is counter productive.

Comment: I don't understand "... will cause me to the bus."  Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 1):

You could say ***I have a better use for my time***, but you better have an acual use for your time that is actually better; otherwise, it will sound as self-absorbed, dismissive, and lazy as 'I can't be bothered' always does.

Comment: +1 Maybe the inevitable "Like what?" follow-up question could be avoided (or at least postponed) with "It's [just] not worth my time."

Comment: @PapaPoule I'd respond to this but I have to go wash my hair.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you are *apathetic* about it.

> **Apathetic** *adjective*
>   Showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apathetic)

Comment: @JoanMiddlemiss Though your effort suggests you aren't. :)

Answer (score 0):

To quote Barbara Bush, **"So why should I waste my beautiful mind on something like that?”**
You could always say, **"Why would I care,"** or **"Why would I bother,"** but the context around the Barbara Bush quote makes it a much more delicious phrase.
Personally I like hyperbole in this sort of case. **"I would rather {insert something really horrid here.}"**